# Command-Line Building

Tags: c#, winforms

I used [Command-Line Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0CoD.jpg) and every time I run my application, a console also appears in the background. How should get rid of this? Please see image:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the command line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`/target` command line option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h25dztx.aspx), with the value `winexe`:

```
csc /target:winexe MyCode.cs
```